# Disable deselect in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables http://datatables.net/index. Is it possible do disable deselect on selected row? I mean where row is selected and has class `row_selected` then when I clicked it again it still be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var oTable;
var giRedraw = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */
    $("#example tbody").click(function(event) {
        $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
            $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
        });
        $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
    });

    /* Add a click handler for the delete row */
    $('#delete').click( function() {
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected[0] );
    } );

    /* Init the table */
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable( );
} );


/* Get the rows which are currently selected */
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    var aReturn = new Array();
    var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

    for ( var i=0 ; i<aTrs.length ; i++ )
    {
        if ( $(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected') )
        {
            aReturn.push( aTrs[i] );
        }
    }
    return aReturn;
}
```

more info / demo here: http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html